# error this.style is undefined inside an event handler passed ona react compopnent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi i'm trying to make a drag and drop application but i can't set the style of the element inside the onDragStart event handeler, this my code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import {classify} from '../functions/functions'

export default class Actions extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.dragstart = this.dragstart.bind(this)
    }
    dragstart(e){
        console.log(e)
            e.style.opacity = .4
            let id = e.id;
            console.log(id)
    }
    render(){

        let name = classify(this.props.name);
        return  <div className={this.props.class} draggable='true' onDragStart={this.dragstart}>
                    <img className="default actions-icon" src={'./icons/'+name+'/'+name+'-.svg'}/>
                    <span className="default">{name}</span>
                </div>
    }
}
```

i appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set style properties on the event and not the event target. `event.target.style.opacity = .4` would fix the error.

However, rather than manually manipulating the DOM it might make more sense to use React [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

For example, we could have opacity start at a default of `1` and change it only when we start/stop dragging.

e.g. [Online Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6l1l8ppwyn)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      opacity: 1,
    }

    this.handleDragStart = this.handleDragStart.bind(this)
    this.handleDragEnd = this.handleDragEnd.bind(this)
  }

  handleDragStart(event) {
    this.setState({ opacity: 0.4 })
  }

  handleDragEnd() {
    this.setState({ opacity: 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const { opacity } = this.state

    return (
      <div
        draggable
        style={{ opacity }}
        onDragStart={this.handleDragStart}
        onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}
      >
        Drag me
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Craig Ayre, i'm just starting with react redux and i'm havung a lot o trouble